# C++: Getting information from a Listbox with LB_GETCURSEL and LB_GETTEXT

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a Listbox with a list of foders. I want to show the name of the folder the user double click. To do so, I have written:

...

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    char Temp[_MAX_DIR]

    switch (message)
        {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
            wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
            // Analizar las selecciones de menú:
            switch (wmId)
            {

            case ID_LIST:

                       SelIndex = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L);  
                       SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)(int)(SelIndex), (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(Temp));

                        printf("The folder is: %s\n", Temp);

                        ...
```

The most relevant lines are:

**SelIndex = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L);

SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)(int)(SelIndex), (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(Temp));**

With the first one I should get the line of the list box the user have clicked, and with the second one I should store into Temp the text that appears in the clicked line. But I get nothing, what am I doing wrong??

Thank you

/////////////////Combining the answers of some users, a script that works is like follows:

```
switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Analizar las selecciones de menú:

        if (wmEvent == LBN_DBLCLK)
        {
            if(wmId == ID_LIST)
            {

                SelIndex = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L); 

                printf("The index is %d\n", SelIndex);

                len = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)(int)(SelIndex), (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(Temp));



                printf("Lenght is %d\n", len);



                printf("The folder is: %s\n",Temp);
```

Comment: Your project isn't UNICODE, right?

Comment: Be more precise. You cannot get nothing. What value is placed into `SelIndex`.

Comment: @M.C. No, I changed it to Multibyte

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wasn't checking what I got in the variable SelIndex, thanks for the recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of more points in addition to what @DavidHeffernan mentioned in his answer:

a) the logic for `case ID_LIST` should be within `if (wmEvent == LBN_DBLCLK)`

b) `printf()` will not do anything in a windows application, try [OutputDebugString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead for debug builds or a `MessageBox()`

Comment: The key of the problem was your first point. About the second one, I always solve it with: 

AllocConsole(); freopen("CONOUT\$", "w", stdout);

Answer (score 3):

Your program has some problems. First of all you seem to be doing a lot more casting than you need to. That's always a worry. You also neglect basic error checking. For instance:

```
SelIndex = SendMessage(hList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L);
```

You assign to `SelIndex` but don't check for errors. The documentation tells you that in the event of error, `LB_ERR` is returned. You must check for that.

Next up is:

```
SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXT, (WPARAM)(int)(SelIndex), (LPARAM)(LPCTSTR)(Temp));
```

The casting seems extreme. You could write it like this:

```
SendMessage(hList, LB_GETTEXT, SelIndex, (LPARAM)Temp);
```

You should also capture the return value and check for errors. Again, you must consult the documentation carefully.

Now, the most likely cause of problems is that you are compiling a Unicode project. And so are expected to supply a buffer of wide characters. So change the declaration of `Temp` like so:

```
wchar_t Temp[_MAX_DIR];
```

Another possible problem is that you are expected to supply a buffer of sufficient length for the string, and the null-terminator. Again, the documentation makes this clear. Use `LB_GETTEXTLEN` to find out how large a buffer you need.

**Note**: I was assuming that your code does actually execute. But the other answers suggest that your code may not execute. In which case that's the first thing to sort out. Confirming facts like that is a basic part of debugging and is something that you must learn to do. So, irrespective of what fixes the problem, the best advice I can give you is to try learn how to diagnose and describe a problem better. Doing that makes it much easier for you to narrow the problem down and so find the solution. In other words here, the main problem you had, in my view, was that you had not fully identified your problem.

Comment: You were right in all you said, but the code did execute, it just printed rubbish. I did what you recommend about printing the value of SelIndex, and I got 0 always. So the problem was there. And I did as @EdwardClements commented, about changing the if() and it worked.
Thank you very much for your answer!!

Comment: It's cool. I'm just trying to help for the future. Being able to debug and diagnose behaviour is really important. That's all I'm saying. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm creating a Listbox with a list of foders.I want to show the name of the folder the user double click.

You can use simple list box to do that, or you can use [DlgDirList function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761366%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do that-all you need to do is to pass `DDL_DIRECTORY` as the last parameter. This function always adds **file names as well** to the list box, so you will need to find a way to filter them on your own. Also, notice that it provides `HWND` of the static control that will display the name of the folder, so this might be useful to you ( this parameter can be `NULL` if you do not wish to use static control ).

---

**NOTE ABOUT `DlgDirList`:**

Directory names have square brackets like this : `[directory]`.

---

> But I get nothing, what am I doing wrong??

You get **some result**. You can not just appear here and say "I get nothing". Explain what is the behavior you get, and what is the one you expected.

### THE SOLUTION:

After looking at your code, I can see what could be wrong-you haven't handled the [LBN_DBLCLK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) notification message.

Also. note that **your list box has to have `LBS_NOTIFY`** style in order to send notification messages to your parent window.

If you provide more detailed explanation of the problem community will have better chance to help you. So far this is the only relevant problem I see in your code.

### RESOURCES ( these should help you to solve your problem ):

*Microsoft* has two good examples for populating list boxes and extracting data from them.

1. If you are OK with allowing the user to see **both files and directories** then you can use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example, just do not forget the `DDL_DIRECTORY` flag I mentioned above.
2. If you **only want directories** in your list box than you will find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example useful.

### EXAMPLE:

To help you with those examples, I have made a demo application that demonstrates both ways.

This code shows you how to populate list box with your data and how to extract strings on  double clicks.

Just go to *File* and choose one of two options to see the demonstration.

First option in the menu lists the data of the player when you double click the item in the edit control ( I have modified `Microsoft's` second example from above ), while the second option lists **files** in your **current directory** and deletes the file you double click on.

In my opinion, **the solution you seek** is best illustrated in the dialog procedure `ListBoxExampleProc`. Pay attention how the items are added ( `WM_INITDIALOG` handler ) and how I get the string from items on double click ( in `WM_COMMAND` handler find and study `case IDC_LIST1` ).

**You will need to implement your desired behavior on your own ( obtaining the directory names and populating the list box properly )** since I had no time to do that for you-Christnmas has passed so no gifts for you this time :)

Hopefully this will help you. If you have further questions leave a comment and I will respond.

Best regards.

INSTRUCTIONS:

Create `default Win32 project` in `Visual Studio`. **Name it "list box test".**

Then all you have to do is to replace the original text of the following files with my code:

`stdafx.h`:

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files:
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <Strsafe.h>

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

`Resource.h`:

```
//{{NO_DEPENDENCIES}}
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated include file.
// Used by list box test.rc
//
#define IDC_MYICON                      2
#define IDD_LISTBOXTEST_DIALOG          102
#define IDS_APP_TITLE                   103
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX                    103
#define IDM_ABOUT                       104
#define IDM_EXIT                        105
#define IDI_LISTBOXTEST                 107
#define IDI_SMALL                       108
#define IDC_LISTBOXTEST                 109
#define IDR_MAINFRAME                   128
#define IDD_DIALOG1                     129
#define IDD_DIALOG2                     130
#define IDC_LIST1                       1000
#define IDC_EDIT1                       1002
#define IDS_PATHTOFILL                  1003
#define ID_FILE_SIMPLELISTBOX           32771
#define ID_FILE_DIRECTORYLISTBOX        32772
#define IDC_STATIC                      -1

// Next default values for new objects
// 
#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#ifndef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
#define _APS_NO_MFC                     1
#define _APS_NEXT_RESOURCE_VALUE        131
#define _APS_NEXT_COMMAND_VALUE         32773
#define _APS_NEXT_CONTROL_VALUE         1004
#define _APS_NEXT_SYMED_VALUE           110
#endif
#endif
```

`list box test.rc`:

```
// Microsoft Visual C++ generated resource script.
//
#include "resource.h"

#define APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 2 resource.
//
#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
#include "targetver.h"
#endif
#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS
#include "windows.h"
#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#undef APSTUDIO_READONLY_SYMBOLS

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// English (U.S.) resources

#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
#ifdef _WIN32
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252)
#endif //_WIN32

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Icon
//

// Icon with lowest ID value placed first to ensure application icon
// remains consistent on all systems.
IDI_LISTBOXTEST         ICON                    "list box test.ico"
IDI_SMALL               ICON                    "small.ico"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Menu
//

IDC_LISTBOXTEST MENU 
BEGIN
    POPUP "&File"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "Simple list box",             ID_FILE_SIMPLELISTBOX
        MENUITEM "Directory list box",          ID_FILE_DIRECTORYLISTBOX
        MENUITEM "E&xit",                       IDM_EXIT
    END
    POPUP "&Help"
    BEGIN
        MENUITEM "&About ...",                  IDM_ABOUT
    END
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Accelerator
//

IDC_LISTBOXTEST ACCELERATORS 
BEGIN
    "?",            IDM_ABOUT,              ASCII,  ALT
    "/",            IDM_ABOUT,              ASCII,  ALT
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Dialog
//

IDD_ABOUTBOX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 170, 62
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "About list box test"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 0, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    ICON            128,IDC_STATIC,14,14,21,20
    LTEXT           "list box test, Version 1.0",IDC_STATIC,42,14,114,8,SS_NOPREFIX
    LTEXT           "Copyright (C) 2014",IDC_STATIC,42,26,114,8
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,113,41,50,14,WS_GROUP
END

IDD_DIALOG1 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 335, 180
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,159,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,278,159,50,14
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,23,14,99,140,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    EDITTEXT        IDC_EDIT1,140,34,179,22,ES_MULTILINE | ES_AUTOHSCROLL | ES_READONLY
END

IDD_DIALOG2 DIALOGEX 0, 0, 316, 180
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,205,159,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,259,159,50,14
    LISTBOX         IDC_LIST1,24,17,173,141,LBS_SORT | LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
    LTEXT           "",IDS_PATHTOFILL,209,31,90,18,0,WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE
    CTEXT           "Current working directory:",IDC_STATIC,209,18,89,9,SS_ENDELLIPSIS
END


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// DESIGNINFO
//

#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
GUIDELINES DESIGNINFO 
BEGIN
    IDD_ABOUTBOX, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 163
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 55
    END

    IDD_DIALOG1, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 328
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 173
    END

    IDD_DIALOG2, DIALOG
    BEGIN
        LEFTMARGIN, 7
        RIGHTMARGIN, 309
        TOPMARGIN, 7
        BOTTOMMARGIN, 173
    END
END
#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


#ifdef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// TEXTINCLUDE
//

1 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "resource.h\0"
END

2 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED\r\n"
    "#include ""targetver.h""\r\n"
    "#endif\r\n"
    "#define APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "#include ""windows.h""\r\n"
    "#undef APSTUDIO_HIDDEN_SYMBOLS\r\n"
    "\0"
END

3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "\r\n"
    "\0"
END

#endif    // APSTUDIO_INVOKED


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// String Table
//

STRINGTABLE 
BEGIN
    IDS_APP_TITLE           "list box test"
    IDC_LISTBOXTEST         "LISTBOXTEST"
END

#endif    // English (U.S.) resources
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



#ifndef APSTUDIO_INVOKED
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#endif    // not APSTUDIO_INVOKED
```

`list box test.cpp`:

```
// list box test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "list box test.h"

#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100

// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
TCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
TCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name

//*********** Variables required for the second list box example

typedef struct 
{ 
    TCHAR achName[MAX_PATH]; 
    TCHAR achPosition[12]; 
    int nGamesPlayed; 
    int nGoalsScored; 
} Player; 

Player Roster[] = 
{ 
    {TEXT("Haas, Jonathan"), TEXT("Midfield"), 18, 4 }, 
    {TEXT("Pai, Jyothi"), TEXT("Forward"), 36, 12 }, 
    {TEXT("Hanif, Kerim"), TEXT("Back"), 26, 0 }, 
    {TEXT("Anderberg, Michael"), TEXT("Back"), 24, 2 }, 
    {TEXT("Jelitto, Jacek"), TEXT("Midfield"), 26, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Raposo, Rui"), TEXT("Back"), 24, 3}, 
    {TEXT("Joseph, Brad"), TEXT("Forward"), 13, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Bouchard, Thomas"), TEXT("Forward"), 28, 5 }, 
    {TEXT("Salmre, Ivo "), TEXT("Midfield"), 27, 7 }, 
    {TEXT("Camp, David"), TEXT("Midfield"), 22, 3 }, 
    {TEXT("Kohl, Franz"), TEXT("Goalkeeper"), 17, 0 }, 
}; 

//**************************************************

// Forward declarations of functions included in this code module:
ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK        WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
INT_PTR CALLBACK        About(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                 HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                 LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                 int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_LISTBOXTEST, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LISTBOXTEST));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}



//
//  FUNCTION: MyRegisterClass()
//
//  PURPOSE: Registers the window class.
//
//  COMMENTS:
//
//    This function and its usage are only necessary if you want this code
//    to be compatible with Win32 systems prior to the 'RegisterClassEx'
//    function that was added to Windows 95. It is important to call this function
//    so that the application will get 'well formed' small icons associated
//    with it.
//
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_LISTBOXTEST));
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_LISTBOXTEST);
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));

   return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

//
//   FUNCTION: InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int)
//
//   PURPOSE: Saves instance handle and creates main window
//
//   COMMENTS:
//
//        In this function, we save the instance handle in a global variable and
//        create and display the main program window.
//
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;

    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

    hWnd = CreateWindow(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

//************ Modified second example of the list box *****************//
//*********** from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298365%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

INT_PTR CALLBACK ListBoxExampleProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, 
    WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            // Add items to list. 
            HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1);  
            for (int i = 0; i < ARRAYSIZE(Roster); i++) 
            { 
                int pos = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, 
                    (LPARAM) Roster[i].achName); 
                // we do not need the rest from Microsoft's example
            } 
            // Set input focus to the list box.
            SetFocus(hwndList); 
            return TRUE;               
        } 

    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
        case IDCANCEL:
          EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
          return TRUE;

        case IDC_LIST1:
            {
                switch (HIWORD(wParam)) 
                { 
                case LBN_DBLCLK:
                    {
                        HWND hwndList = GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1); 

                        // Get selected index.
                        int lbItem = (int)SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0); 

                        // display item's text 
                        TCHAR buff[MAX_PATH];
                        SendMessage(hwndList, LB_GETTEXT, lbItem, (LPARAM)buff);

                        SetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_EDIT1, buff); 
                        return TRUE; 
                    } 
                }
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

//************ Modified first example of the list box **************//
//*********** from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

INT_PTR CALLBACK DlgDelFileProc(HWND hDlg, UINT message, 
    UINT wParam, LONG lParam) 
{ 
    PTSTR pszCurDir; 
    PTSTR pszFileToDelete; 
    int iLBItem; 
    int cStringsRemaining; 
    int iRet; 
    TCHAR achBuffer[MAX_PATH]; 
    TCHAR achTemp[MAX_PATH]; 
    BOOL fResult;     

    switch (message) 
    { 
        case WM_INITDIALOG: 

            // Initialize the list box by filling it with files from 
            // the current directory. 
            pszCurDir = achBuffer; 
            GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, pszCurDir); 
            DlgDirList(hDlg, pszCurDir, IDC_LIST1, IDS_PATHTOFILL, DDL_DIRECTORY); 
            SetFocus(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1)); 
            return FALSE; 

        case WM_COMMAND: 

            switch (LOWORD(wParam)) 
            { 
            case IDC_LIST1: 
                if( HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_DBLCLK )
                {

                    // When the user double clicks the item, 
                    // first retrieve the selected file. 
                    pszFileToDelete = achBuffer; 
                    DlgDirSelectEx(hDlg, pszFileToDelete, MAX_PATH, IDC_LIST1); 

                    // Make sure the user really wants to delete the file.
                    achTemp[MAX_PATH];
                    StringCbPrintf (achTemp, ARRAYSIZE(achTemp),
                        TEXT("Are you sure you want to delete %s?"), 
                    pszFileToDelete);
                    iRet = MessageBox(hDlg, achTemp, L"Deleting Files", 
                               MB_YESNO | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                    if (iRet == IDNO)
                        return TRUE;

                    // Delete the file.
                    fResult = DeleteFile(pszFileToDelete); 
                    if (!fResult) 
                    { 
                        MessageBox(hDlg, L"Could not delete file.", NULL, MB_OK); 
                    } 
                    else // Remove the filename from the list box.
                    { 
                         // Get the selected item.
                         iLBItem = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1),
                                       LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0); 

                         // Delete the selected item.
                         cStringsRemaining = SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1),
                                                 LB_DELETESTRING, iLBItem, 0); 

                         // If this is not the last item, set the selection to 
                         // the item immediately following the one just deleted.
                         // Otherwise, set the selection to the last item.
                         if (cStringsRemaining > iLBItem) 
                         { 

                             SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1), LB_SETCURSEL,
                                 iLBItem, 0); 
                         } 
                         else 
                         { 

                             SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_LIST1), LB_SETCURSEL, 
                                 cStringsRemaining, 0); 
                         } 
                    } 
                }
                break; 

            case IDOK: 
            case IDCANCEL: 

                // Destroy the dialog box. 
                EndDialog(hDlg, TRUE); 
                return TRUE; 

            default: 
                return FALSE; 
        } 

    default: 
        return FALSE; 
    } 
} 

//
//  FUNCTION: WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM)
//
//  PURPOSE:  Processes messages for the main window.
//
//  WM_COMMAND  - process the application menu
//  WM_PAINT    - Paint the main window
//  WM_DESTROY  - post a quit message and return
//
//
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        wmId    = LOWORD(wParam);
        wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
        // Parse the menu selections:
        switch (wmId)
        {
        case ID_FILE_SIMPLELISTBOX:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), hWnd, ListBoxExampleProc);
            break;
        case ID_FILE_DIRECTORYLISTBOX:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG2), hWnd, DlgDelFileProc);
            break;
        case IDM_ABOUT:
            DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
            break;
        case IDM_EXIT:
            DestroyWindow(hWnd);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        // TODO: Add any drawing code here...
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

// Message handler for about box.
INT_PTR CALLBACK About(HWND hDlg, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return (INT_PTR)TRUE;

    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDOK || LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        {
            EndDialog(hDlg, LOWORD(wParam));
            return (INT_PTR)TRUE;
        }
        break;
    }
    return (INT_PTR)FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It is a little bit complex for my level, but you have made a really nice explanation about it. So thank you!!

Comment: @nacho22:
 
Glad I could help. The working example of what you need can be found in dialog procedure `ListBoxExampleProc`. You have everything there-it is the same as the accepted solution, only I have wrapped it in the working program. Also, the second dialog procedure shows you the second way to do what you want. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what I get is first letter of selected listbox element.

```
        //hEdit 2 - edit widnow, hWndList - listbox window

        char z[20] = {"hhhhh"};
        LRESULT SelIndex;
        SelIndex = SendMessage(hWndList, LB_GETCURSEL, 0, 0L);
        tmp_str = std::to_string(SelIndex);
        SendMessage(hWndList, LB_GETTEXT, SelIndex, (LPARAM)z);
        SetWindowTextA(hEdit2, z);
```